# How to show the google maps on Android Apk Application?

Tags: java, android, maps, apk

I'm trying more than 2 days to get google maps work in android app.
At first when I tried to do this with the Emulator, it didn't show the map only a Grid.
So, later on I tried to Export the App to Apk and to install it directly into my Galaxy note 2.
In the phone it showed the same = Grid with Minus and Plus at the bottom.(Same as the Emulator did).
Now I thought that it may be my API Key (with Google maps v2 turned on), but I followed the Instructions carefully and did it properly.
So, At the Bottom Line, I have the Libraries needed (android-support-v4.jar+google-play-services.jar), and nothing works, the map doesn't appear.

Does someone know how to solve this issue ?

My MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.map;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;



public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

{

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main,menu);
        return true;
```

}

My activity_main.xml layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >



<fragment 
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my Manifest.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.map"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<permission
android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


<activity
android:name="com.example.map.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyD5dqdfd0TLVBzugqqJ_-4OKqWs_MojR4Y"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide some more concrete information and details. Since the code behaves the same way on the phone as in the emulator, it looks as though the problem is in your code/build rather than the way you're deploying it.

Comment: Hi, I just added the code. @LiverpoolFTW

Answer (score 0):

Google api console-> Services has two choice. They are closed.

1-Google Maps Android API v2
2-Google Maps API v2

Check choice 1(Google Maps Android API v2).

Comment: My choice is the Google Maps Android API v2.